# Combining multiple column into one in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like below:

```
Table A
----------
ID   Field1 Field2 Field3
1     A     NULL   B
2     B     NULL   NULL 
3     C     A      NULL 
4     A     D      NULL
```

The requirement is to combine all the Fields (except ID) into one, so that Table will look like as below:

```
Table A
-------
ID   Field
1     A   
2     B    
3     C   
4     D
```

Any order will be okay though the values have to be distinct. This means that Field1 to Field3 needs to be one column (in any temp table) and have distinct values. I used ID columns just to clarify the result however ID is not required. Currently I'm using union for the desired output
e.g.

```
select distinct Field
from
(Select Field1 as Field from TableA
where Field1 is not null
union
Select Field2 from TableA
where Field2 is not null
union
Select Field3 from TableA
where Field3 is not null
)
```

I'm sure that there is better way of achieving the same output with less line of codes.

Comment: Why is `ID 1 = A`? Why is `ID 3 = C`? Why is `ID 4 = D`?

Comment: You need to explain your rules better. Why do D and C win out over A, but A wins out over B? Is this some new variation to rock paper scissors lizard spock?

Comment: Unique values from the 3 columns? If so what governs the ID they are assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `UNION` solution is about as close as you can get to what you want. I would clean it up a little though, like this:

```
SELECT Field FROM (
    SELECT Field1 AS Field  FROM TableA UNION
    SELECT Field2           FROM TableA UNION
    SELECT Field3           FROM TableA
) a
WHERE Field IS NOT NULL;
```

I tightened up the sub query by moving the `WHERE` clause to the outside. Also, you don't need `DISTINCT` on the outside, since `UNION` already provides a distinct result.

Comment: what does the **a** stand for?

Comment: @Shaharyar, a the sub query alias, as required.

Answer (score 0):

I updated what I originally had with this. It appears to work on my end with the test data that you provided.

```
Create Table #temp
(
ID Int,
Field varchar(100)
)

Create Table #a
(
ID Int,
Field1 varchar(5) Null,
Field2 varchar(5) Null,
Field3 varchar(5) Null
)

Insert Into #a Values (1, 'A', null, 'B')
Insert Into #a Values (1, 'B', null, null)
Insert Into #a Values (1, 'C', 'A', null)
Insert Into #a Values (1, 'A', 'D', null)

Select * From #a

Insert Into #temp
Select  ID,
    Field = 
    (
        Case When Field1 IS NOT NULL Then Field1 + ' ' Else '' End +
        Case When Field2 IS NOT NULL Then Field2 + ' ' Else '' End +
        Case When Field3 IS NOT NULL Then Field3 + ' ' Else '' End
    )
From #a

Select * From #temp

--Rename your new consolidated table to the real table name that you want

Drop Table #a
Drop Table #temp
```

Comment: Hi Ganders, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @GargiNarain Can you tell me where I'm wrong and I'll fix...if you're still needing help.

Comment: Ganders, you actually concatenated the columns where in I'm looking for distinct values in one column.